# SQL aggregate column issue

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need to find the top applicants from last week but I am getting errors in my SQL query.

```
  var queryString = "select id, created_at, user_id, count(id) as cnt from "+
      "applications where id in (select id from applications where "+
      "created_at > current_date - interval '1 week') group by user_id";
```

**data.sql**

```
insert into listings (id, created_at, created_by, name, description) values
    (1, '2015-01-15 11:00', 1, 'Join us conquering the world!', 'This is your best chance to be on the right side of the equation...')
;

insert into listings (id, created_at, created_by, name, description) values
    (1, '2015-01-15 11:00', 1, 'Join us conquering the world!', 'This is your best chance to be on the right side of the equation...')
;

insert into listings (id, created_at, created_by, name, description) values
    (2, '2017-01-29 11:00', 1, 'Join us conquering the world!', 'Holla ho')
;

insert into listings (id, created_at, created_by, name, description) values
    (3, '2017-01-15 11:00', 1, 'Join us conquering the world!', 'Hey ya')
;

insert into applications (created_at, user_id, listing_id, cover_letter) values
    ('2017-02-23 12:00', 2, 1, 'Hello, ...')
;

INSERT INTO APPLICATIONS (CREATED_AT, USER_ID, LISTING_ID, COVER_LETTER) VALUES
    ('2017-02-24 12:00', 2, 2, 'HELLO, ...')
;

INSERT INTO APPLICATIONS (CREATED_AT, USER_ID, LISTING_ID, COVER_LETTER) VALUES
    ('2017-02-22 12:00', 2, 2, 'HELLO, ...')
;

INSERT INTO APPLICATIONS (CREATED_AT, USER_ID, LISTING_ID, COVER_LETTER) VALUES
    ('2017-02-25 12:00', 3, 1, 'HELLO, ...')
;
```

And here is the error:

```
column "applications.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

What I am doing wrong?

So, basically I would like to see user id `2` with `3` applications and user id `3` with `1` application.

Comment: please tag the dbms you are using.

Comment: The error is very clear. You need to add the 'applications.Id'  to the group by clause.

Comment: @FeryalBadili not that simple. In OP's query he `select id, created_at,...` so to pass error at least he need `id` and `created_at` column in GROUP BY. But I think OP is working with a wrong query at first, he just didn't fully understand his intention for `COUNT` function.

Answer (score 1):

You might intend this query:

```
select user_id, count(id) as cnt
from applications
where id in (select id
             from applications 
             where created_at > current_date - interval '1 week'
            )
group by user_id;
```

Note the columns that are removed from the `select`.

If we assume that `id` is actually unique, you can do:

```
select user_id, count(id) as cnt
from applications
group by user_id
having max(created_at) > current_date - interval '1 week';
```